# How to use default Semantic UI React Dropdown keyboard navigation with custom styling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to use default keyboard navigation from `Semantic UI React Dropdown` (arrows to move to prev/next item, enter to select etc.) with custom Dropdown styling.

Everything was working until I added `Dropdown.Menu` and `Dropdown.Item` components just to do `className={style.item}` etc. After that all default mechanics such as search, keyboard navigation, currently selected item stopped working. I re-added everything manually, but cannot get keyboard navigation to work again.

Previously - working, but without styling

```js
<Dropdown
  ref={field}
  fluid
  search
  selection
  selectOnNavigation={false}
  name="listId"
  options={selectedBoard.lists.map((list) => ({
     text: list.name,
     value: list.id,
   }))}
  value={selectedList && selectedList.id}
  placeholder={selectedList && selectedList.name}
  className={styles.field}
  onChange={handleSubmit}
  onBlur={handleSubmit}
  onClose={handleSubmit}
  wrapSelection={false}
  searchInput={{ autoFocus: true }}
/>
```

Now - keyboard navigation not working, but I can style every element

```js
<Dropdown
  ref={field}
  fluid
  selectOnNavigation={false}
  name="listId"
  value={selectedList && selectedList.id}
  onSearchChange={handleSearchChange}
  search={filterLists}
  placeholder={selectedList && selectedList.name}
  className={styles.field}
  onChange={handleSubmit}
  onBlur={handleSubmit}
  onClose={handleSubmit}
  wrapSelection={false}
  searchInput={{ autoFocus: true }}
>
  <Dropdown.Menu className={classNames(styles.fieldMenu)}>
    {filteredLists.map((list) => (
      <Dropdown.Item
        className={styles.fieldItem}
        key={list.id}
        text={list.name}
        value={list.id}
        active={selectedList.id === list.id}
        selected={selectedList.id === list.id}
        onClick={handleItemClick}
      />
    ))}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Functions that might affect it

```js
const handleItemClick = (_, __) => {
    field.current.handleItemClick(_, __);
};

const filterLists = (_e, searchQuery) => {
  const filteredList = selectedBoard.lists.filter((item) => !searchQuery || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()));
  return filteredList;
};

const handleSearchChange = (_e, { searchQuery }) => {
  const filteredList = filterLists(_e, searchQuery);
  setFilteredLists(filteredList);
};
```

Is there any property that I'm missing and it needs to be set in order for keyboard navigation to work? Or is it possible to style `Dropdown.Item` and `Dropdown.Menu` without adding extra elements to the hierarchy?

Comment: @100grams No, I did everything that I wanted from scratch using basic html elements. This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but you can check out semi-working version [here](https://github.com/RARgames/4gaBoards/blob/feat-cardModal/client/src/lib/custom-ui/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.jsx)